# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape

Tags: keras

My code is giving a valueError. Does anyone know why?

`ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_3 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape`

This is my code:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(4, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 9))
classifier.add(Dense(4, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 5, epochs = 100)
```

Comment: Could you provide complete Traceback